# What is the difference between C-x and C-c and the concept behind it?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

I was asking a [similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/26309/12999) about the main concept behind default emacs key bindings. But this one is more specific to `C-c` and `C-x`.

I know and use some commands/functions/features bind to `C-c` or `C-x` by default. I also have my own cheat sheet for that.

The **problem** ist that I often got the two mixed up. It would help my brain to understand the concept (if there is one) behind that two major keys.
Most of time I remember the key-binding for a special command but did not remember if I need to start it with `C-c` or `C-x`.

Are there a special type of function always going to `C-c` and another type that always (or most) goes to `C-x`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal `C-x` keymap is for global bindings which are expected to do something regardless of the active modes.  Conversely:

> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ followed by a control character or a
> digit are reserved for major modes.
>
> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ followed by ‘{’, ‘}’, ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘:’
> or ‘;’ are also reserved for major modes.
>
> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ followed by any other ASCII
> punctuation or symbol character are allocated for minor modes.

-- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Key Binding Conventions`

Also:

> Sequences consisting of ‘C-c’ and a letter (either upper or lower
> case) are reserved for users.

Although those would commonly be global bindings.